# In Django, querysets with multiple models evaluate very slowly

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project which I'm using to learn about optimizing searches in Django. I'm running Django 3.2 with a Postgres backend in a Docker container. I have two models, `Chant` and `Sequence`, which have the same fields, one view per model to search for instances of that model, and a combined search view, which searches for instances of both models and displays the results in a combined list. When I populate the database with a bunch of objects and try searching for things, the combined search view runs significantly slower than when searching for instances of a single model.

Here are the relevant parts of my `models.py`:

```py
from django.db import models

class Chant(models.Model):
    std_full_text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Sequence(models.Model):
    std_full_text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is `views/chant.py` (`views/sequence.py` is the same, but with "sequence" and "Sequence" substituted for "chant" and "Chant"):

```py
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.views.generic import ListView
from main_app.models import Chant

class ChantSearchView(ListView):
    model = Chant
    template_name = 'chant_search.html'
    context_object_name = 'chants'
    paginate_by = 100

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            return Chant.objects.filter(std_full_text__icontains=query)
        else:
            return Chant.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        query = self.request.GET.get('q', '')
        page_number = self.request.GET.get('page', 1)
        paginator = Paginator(self.get_queryset(), self.paginate_by)
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
        context['query'] = query
        context['page_obj'] = page_obj
        return context
```

And here's `views/combined.py`:

```py
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.views.generic import ListView
from main_app.models import Chant, Sequence

class CombinedSearchView(ListView):
    model = Chant
    template_name = 'combined_search.html'
    context_object_name = 'results'
    paginate_by = 100

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            chant_results = Chant.objects.filter(std_full_text__icontains=query)
            sequence_results = Sequence.objects.filter(std_full_text__icontains=query)
            return chant_results.union(sequence_results)
        else:
            return Chant.objects.union(Sequence.objects.all())

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        query = self.request.GET.get('q', '')
        page_number = self.request.GET.get('page', 1)
        paginator = Paginator(self.get_queryset(), self.paginate_by)
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
        context['query'] = query
        context['page_obj'] = page_obj
        return context
```

When I fill the database with 300,000 random chants and 300,000 random sequences and visit each of the pages, I expect the combined search to take at most twice the time to run, since it's searching through twice as many rows in database tables. Instead, it takes more than ten times as long. Using a short search term that matches almost everything in the database ("a"):

```
chant-only search: <0.5 seconds
sequence-only search: <0.5 seconds
chant+sequence search: ~5 seconds
```

And while I was running my scripts to populate the database, I tried visiting the chant and combined views while there were no sequence objects in the database. Here are rough timings for 300,000 chants and 0 sequences:

```
chant-only search: <1 second
chant+sequence search: 3 seconds (!! - to be clear, the sequence queryset contains 0 sequences)
```

My best guess is that `chant_results.union(sequence_results)` is causing things to run more slowly, evidently by an order of magnitude. Why is this be happening, and **is there anything I can do to make the combined search run at a comparable speed to the single-model searches?**

(This test database was set up to explore optimizing search responsiveness for an existing project, with two nearly identical models, Chant and Sequence, similar to those above. Combining these two models is not an option.)

Comment: Really good and interesting question! I don't know a lot about SQL, but could this be an issue with the query language, instead of Django? When I google `sql union takes long time`, there might be some help! (Example of a link I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984706/query-with-a-union-sub-query-takes-a-very-long-time) (Check out the query with a plugin like Django Debug Toolbar https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

Comment: Thank you - you sent me in a very helpful direction! Using `chant_results.union(sequence_results, all=True)` prevents SQL from checking that all results in the new queryset are DISTINCT. Django Debug Toolbar indicates it brings my query time down from about 5000ms to about 800ms.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#union

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.